# Is redis list data structure horizontally scalable

Tags: redis, sharding, redis-cluster

OOTB, will a redis list data structure support sharding - meaning will the elements of a list are stored in same physical machine or will redis hash the elements and distribute them across all available shards.
Any strategy to distribute the elements of a redis list across multiple shards ? if it is possible, will the LRANGE method fetches the elements from shards randomly ? or how does it work

Answer (score 1):

Redis data structures are bounded to a single key, which is associated to a [specific hash slot in a specific shard](https://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial).

If you need to collect data from different list on different shards you should consider either collect them one by one or add a Redis Module like [RedisGears](https://redisgears.io/).